# Transpile Arrow Functions into Named Functions without Variable Assignment

Tags: javascript, babeljs, transpiler

Babel (config below) transpiles the following simple arrow function:

```
const clipboard = id => {
  const scratchpad = document.createElement('input');
  scratchpad.value = document.getElementById(id).innerText;
  document.body.appendChild(scratchpad);
  scratchpad.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(scratchpad);
}
```

...into the following:

```
var clipboard = function clipboard(id) {
  var scratchpad = document.createElement('input');
  scratchpad.value = document.getElementById(id).innerText;
  document.body.appendChild(scratchpad);
  scratchpad.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(scratchpad);
};
```

The result I **want** to produce is this:

```
function clipboard(id) {
  var scratchpad = document.createElement('input');
  scratchpad.value = document.getElementById(id).innerText;
  document.body.appendChild(scratchpad);
  scratchpad.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(scratchpad);
};
```

In other words, I want Babel to transpile assigned arrow functions into ES5 named functions *without* assigning the function to a variable.  **Is this possible, and if so, how?**

My build pipeline includes an uglify task, which mangles variable names (but not function names).  I can use uglify's `mangle: { reserved: [] }` option, but that would require manually tracking every named arrow function.

---

From package.json:

```
"browserslist": "defaults",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "useBuiltIns": "usage",
          "corejs": "3.6.5"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Why do you care? No, this is generally not possible, as the `const` declaration and the function expression are handled separately (and changing it to a function declaration is semantically wrong). Of course you could write your own babel plugin to do that.

Comment: I care because of how gulp-uglify mangles variables (but not named functions).  It's just vanilla JS that's getting compiled and loaded into the browser via <script>.  User events that trigger the function return "undefined" because the function (var) has been arbitrarily renamed.  Thanks for the custom plugin suggestion.

Comment: The transform you're asking for will also cause the function to be hoisted, potentially introducing different runtime behavior, which is why Babel doesn't do that. Are you explicitly passing `toplevel: true` to Uglify? Otherwise as far as I know, it shouldn't mangle top-level variables. This all _really_ seems like you should be asking a question about how to configure Uglify, not Babel.

Comment: Thanks, @loganfsmyth - you are correct.  After still more digging, it turns out the real culprit was occurring at a much earlier step in preprocessing.  I was wrapping plain Javascript (via `browserify`) in a way that essentially made the functions inaccessible to the browser.  Uglify wasn't mangling the functions, it was (correctly) identifying them as dead code and dropping them altogether.  (I'm rewriting a bunch of jQuery scripts in plain Javascript, which occasioned fault in the build process.)

Comment: Ahhh that will absolutely do that, glad you were able to track it down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above the answer seems to be, "*You should not want to do this*."

Babel transforms arrow functions as illustrated above in order to avoid potential unintended side effects in production.